# Get list of custom brands extension attribute for current category Magento

Tags: magento, attributes, magento-1.8

I'm using a Magento extension called BELVG brands, which creates a custom brand attribute and gives each of my brands a link to it's own brand page as well as an overall brand page ( where I got this code from )

On my parent category pages I'm trying to show a list of brands just for that particular category, but because the Brand attributes data is stored in the extensions own brands table I'm having trouble with the usual getCollection methods.

I can pull out a list of all brands no problem and my code below does this, you'll see where I'm also getting the id of the category which is not really doing anything as yet because I am stumped as how to integrate this into my current code so I get what I want.

I've tried lot's of variations but I can't get anything to work, and every other way of listing attributes uses the catalog/category collection and filtering which doesn't help me here.

Can someone point me in the right direction? 
I hope I'm being clear here, I don't use stack overflow very often.
Thanks
( Magento Community 1.8 )

```
<?php       
        $catId = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId(); // Get current category id


        $collection = Mage::getModel('brands/brands')->getCollection(); //get collection from brands
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('title', 'description', 'url_key', 'image'))
                ->addAttributeToFilter('active', 1)
                ->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore())
                ->setOrder('title', 'ASC')
```